# Music files opening in Notepad

Tags: python, windows, default, notepad

When I try to open a music file it opens in notepad.

```
 music='C:\\Users\\admin\\Music'
 songs=os.listdir(music)
 print(songs)
 os.startfile(os.path.join(music,songs[0]))
```

Comment: Are you able to double-click on the file and play it? `os.startfile` is equivalent of double-clicking on the file.

Comment: is there a question here... what error are you getting?

Comment: it is problem with settings in your system, not problem with Python code. `startfile()` ask system to open it with default program - and if system has configured `Notepad` for music files then `startfile()` will use `Notepad`. Maybe better use `os.system("program.exe music_file")` to open it with some `program.exe`

Comment: Yes i am able to open to open the music file in vlc

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys I solved my problem using playsound module instead of os.startfile.

ps.playsound(r'C:\Users\admin\Music\Test.mp3')